How to solve the equation $(-x)^{1/x}=4$?
How to solve this equation
$$(-x)^{1/x}=4$$
I approached in this way. writing $-x=4^x$. Now is there any way to
solve this other than a numerical method or graphical method?

Please use Mathjax to format your equations and show your attempt.

Please make the title more informative.

You could use the Lambert-W function and possibly obtain a convoluted way to write the answer.

$-x$ is decreasing and $4^x$ is increasing, so there is at most one solution.
And just poking around, you find $x=-\frac12$ works.

That's great. But is there any way to find the ans without using trial and error?  Also it's obvious the ans has to be negative.

@AfnanShahQureshi I can elaborate on what my personal "poking around" process was. You can decide if there is any value in trying to formalize it. From $-x=4^x$, I decided to eliminate negative signs by effectively letting $y=-x$. So now $y=\frac{1}{4^y}$. Noticing $4$ is a power, I decided to see if anything happened from reducing to base $2$. So now I effectively replace $y$ with $z/2$ and have $\frac{z}{2}=\frac{1}{2^z}$. At this point it's clear that $z=1$ works, and I already had established there is only one solution. So backport $z=1$ to $x=-\frac12$ and that was that.
